# scala play framework parsing error

Tags: scala, playframework

I have 2 foriegn key with same table and it parse into the program get a compilation error
    The problem is **the 2 Id's are get null**

Model Class MyFriend & functions

```
case class MyFriend(id: Pk[Long]= NotAssigned,user_Id:Option[Long],friend_Id:Option[Long],is_accepted:Boolean)
object MyFriend{
  /**
   * parse a Myfreind from a ResultSet.
   */
  val simple ={
    get[Pk[Long]]("myfriend.id") ~
    get[Option[Long]]("myfriend.user_Id")~
    get[Option[Long]]("myfriend.friend_Id")~
    get[Boolean]("myfriend.is_accepted") map{
      case id ~ user_Id ~ friend_Id ~ is_accepted => MyFriend(id, user_Id,friend_Id,is_accepted)
    }
   }


 /**
   * Parse a MyFriend from a userProfile
   */
  val withUserProfile =MyFriend.simple ~ (UserProfile.simple ?) map{
    case myfriend  ~ userprofile => (myfriend, userprofile)
  }
  /**
   * create a new MyFriend.
   *
   * @param myfriend 
   */
  def insert(myFriend: MyFriend): Long = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL(
        """
          insert into MY_FRIEND(USER_ID,FRIEND_ID,IS_ACCEPTED) values (
            {user_Id}, {friend_Id},{is_accepted}
          )
        """).on(
          'user_Id -> myFriend.user_Id,
          'friend_Id -> myFriend.friend_Id,
          'is_accepted -> myFriend.is_accepted
          ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }


/**
   * Update a MyFriend
   *
   * @param  MyFriend
   */
  def update(myFriend:MyFriend)={
  DB.withConnection{ implicit connection =>
    SQL(
        """
        update MY_FRIEND
        set FRIEND_ID = {friend_Id}, IS_ACCEPTED={is_accepted} where USER_ID={use_id}
        """).on(
          'user_Id -> myFriend.user_Id,
          'friend_Id -> myFriend.friend_Id,
          'is_accepted -> myFriend.is_accepted
          ).executeUpdate()

  }

}
/**
   * Find myfriendId Via userprofile
   */
  def authenticate(myFriend: MyFriend) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val myFriendFound = SQL(
        """
          select * from MY_FRIEND 
          where USER_ID = {user_Id} and FRIEND_ID={friend_Id}
        """).on(
          'user_Id -> myFriend.user_Id,
          'friend_Id ->myFriend.friend_Id
          ).as(MyFriend.simple.singleOpt)
      myFriendFound
    }
  }
```

Model UserProfile amd Functions

```
case class UserProfile(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, useraccountid: Option[Long], name: String, date_of_birth: Date, gender: String, image: String,status:String)

object UserProfile{

  /**
   * Parse a UserProfile from a ResultSet
   */
  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("user_profile.id") ~
      get[Option[Long]]("user_profile.user_account_id") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.name") ~
      get[Date]("user_profile.date_of_birth") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.gender") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.image") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.status") map {
        case id ~ user_account_id ~ name ~ date_of_birth ~ gender ~ image ~ status =>
          UserProfile(id, user_account_id, name, date_of_birth, gender, image,status )
      }
  }
 /**
   * Parse a userProfile from a MyFriend
   */
  val withMyFriend =UserProfile.simple ~ (MyFriend.simple ?) map{
    case userprofile  ~ myfriend  => (userprofile, myfriend)
  }
/**
   * Find MyFriend With MyFriend Detail
   */

  def myFriend(user_Id:Long) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val myFriend = SQL(
        """
          select * from MY_FRIEND
          where USER_ID = {user_id}
        """).on(
          'user_Id -> user_Id).as(MyFriend.simple.singleOpt)
      myFriend
    }
  }
  /**
   * Authonticate
   */
  def authenticate(userprofile: UserProfile) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val userProfileFound = SQL(
        """
          select * from USER_PROFILE 
          where ID = (id}
        """).on(
          'Id -> userprofile.id
          ).as(UserProfile.simple.singleOpt)
      userProfileFound
    }
  }
```

Controller Application  method for parse friend and user Id

```
val userprofile:UserProfile=null
        val myfriend:MyFriend=null

   def authenticateFriend = Action { implicit request =>
            val alert: Alert = new Alert("", "")
            Common.setAlert(alert)
            myFriendForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
            errors => BadRequest(views.html.myFriend(errors,userprofile,myfriend)),
        myFriend => {
            val myfriendOpt = MyFriend.authenticate(myFriend)
        myfriendOpt match {

       case Some(authmyfriend: MyFriend) =>
            val userSession = request.session + ("myFriendId" -> authmyfriend.id.toString)
            val friendSession=request.session + ("userProfileId" -> userprofile.id.toString)
            val myFriendOpt = MyFriend.userProfile(authmyfriend.id.get)
       myFriendOpt match {
       case None => Ok(views.html.myFriend(Application.myFriendForm, userprofile,myfriend)).withSession(userSession)
       case Some(userProfileFound: UserProfile) =>
            val myFriendFormWithDetails = Application.myFriendForm.fill(userProfileFound)
            Ok(views.html.myFriend(myFriendFormWithDetails,userprofile,authmyfriend)).withSession(userSession)

            }

          }
      })

  }
```

Create MyFriend Page function

```
     def createMyFriend = Action { implicit request =>
   if (request.session.get("userId") == None) {
      Results.Redirect("/")
    }
   else {
        val myfriends:MyFriend=null
        val userprofileId = request.session.get("myFriendId").get.toLong//userProfileId
        val userprofile = UserProfile.findUserByAccountId(userprofileId).get
        println(userprofile)
        val myfriendId = request.session.get("userProfileId").get.toLong//myFriendId
        val myfriend = MyFriend.friendidByUserIsAccepted(myfriendId,true)
        println(myfriend)
        myFriendForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors => BadRequest(views.html.myFriend(errors, userprofile,myfriends)),
   myFriend => {
          println("errors")
          val myFriendOpt = UserProfile.myFriend(userprofile.id.get)
          println(myFriendOpt)
   myFriendOpt match {
   case None =>
          val updatedMyFriend = MyFriend(NotAssigned,
          Option(userprofileId), Option(myfriendId),myFriend.is_accepted)
          MyFriend.insert(updatedMyFriend)
          val alert: Alert = new Alert("success", " MyFriend Saved")
          Common.setAlert(alert)
          }
          Results.Redirect("/myFriend")
        })  
        }
    }
```

**Redirect To myFriend page**

```
def myFriend = Action { implicit request =>

   Ok(views.html.myFriend(Application.myFriendForm,userprofile,myfriend))
    }
```

Whenrun the program get nullpointer for id's

I am stuck with this problem with couple of days if any one had the same problem and anyone is solved

Comment: Which line is the error ?

Comment: Error Occured Here And the error is pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found : None.type required: models.MyFriend i just update it

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your pattern matching construct.

```
case None => // do some if None
```

or

```
case _ => // something in this case
```

or you can simply ignore this case by omiting right hand side of the arrow

The problem is that you didn't cover all the posible cases in you function. You've covered `Some (authuserProfile:UserProfile)` and `case Some(authmyfriend: MyFriend)`, but not None case and it looks like your method receives None.

**Updated**

The error occurres because you have `_` which matches all cases, so you pattern matching construct just can't reach anything (Some in your case) after `case _ => //...`

If i understood your code correct, the problem is in this part

```
userProfileOpt match {
  case _ => Ok(views.html.myFriend(...).withSession(friendSession)
  case _ =>
    val myFriendFound: UserProfile=null
    val useracc:UserAccount=null
```

Both cases mathes all posible cases, that's an error

Comment: "unreachable code" error occured And compilation error pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found : None.type required: models.MyFriend

Comment: i just update the controller application code and the above error occured

Comment: @ AlexIv thnx... but i change into one case to None then got these error

Comment: i just update that in  case Some(userProfileFound: UserProfile) =>

Answer (score 0):

`UserProfile.myFriend` returns `MyFriend`, not `Option[MyFriend]`. Therefore, your pattern match is incorrect. You can try to fix the `def myFriend` to return `Option`, or remove the pattern match.

(edit): Probably you should change from `MyFriend.simple.single` to `MyFriend.simple.singleOpt`.

As a rule of thumb, always use an explicit return type from public methods. Type inference is very powerful and useful, but use it wisely.

Comment: @lulian Dragos  i just update the Question and get error on compiling

Comment: So the error is when compiling, or when running the app? The exception suggests it's been at runtime. How did you update the code, as I can't see the difference in the question.

Comment: When running the app Error occured...and i update the code in error occured place.. in ApplicationController

Comment: The question still mentions type errors, and no `NoSuchElementException`, which one is it? Paste the whole stack trace if it is the exception.

Comment: sorry for that.. the compilation error was going and i can't get the userProfileId and FriendId they got null and new code i just update it